# qgis and embedded ajax (bing map)

Tags: qgis, python, bing-maps, qt

I need to load in a docked QWebView this html:

```
    < html >
< body >
< iframe width="100%" height="499" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" 
src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/embeddedMap/v1/ajax/BirdseyeWithLabels?zoomLevel=10&pushpins=45.0610173308_7.64466465993&center=45.0610173308_7.64466465993&heading=123" >
< /iframe >
< /body >< /html >
```

I'm using this code:

```
class WebView(QWebView):
def __init__(self, parent=None,framed=False):
    QWebView.__init__(self, parent)
    #QObject.connect(self, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), self.onLoad)
    #QObject.connect(self.page().networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL("sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)"), self.onErrors)
    self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    self.framed = framed

def load(self,url, params):
    mqurl = QUrl.fromUserInput(QString.fromAscii(url))
    p = []
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("url="+url, "WebView")
    for k, v in params.iteritems():
        p.append( (k, v) )
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(k)+'=' + str(v), "WebView")

    mqurl.setQueryItems(p)
    if self.framed==True:
        mhtml=HtmlFrame(mqurl.toString(),self.height()-20)
        qmhtml = QString.fromAscii(mhtml)
        self.setHtml(qmhtml,mqurl)
    else:
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(mqurl)
```

If framed is False it works, if framed is True the webpage is not loaded.
With other webpages it works. 
Is it due to Ajax?
How to solve this? 
Thanks